# GKPeerPickerController has been deprecated in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, ios7

I need the functionality that allows data exchange over blue-tooth between two devices. I know that GKPeerPickerController is used for this purpose. But this class has been deprecated since  iOS 7. Both Internet search and documentation say nothing about what to use instead (as it usually does). Any suggestions?

[GKPeerPickerController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question. From apple docs:

> The Multipeer Connectivity framework (MultipeerConnectivity.framework)
>   supports the discovery of nearby devices and the direct communication
>   with those devices without requiring Internet connectivity. This
>   framework makes it possible to create multipeer sessions easily and to
>   support reliable in-order data transmission and real-time data
>   transmission. With this framework, your app can communicate with
>   nearby devices and seamlessly exchange data.
>
> The framework provides programmatic and UI-based options for
>   discovering and managing network services. Apps can integrate the
>   [MCBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class into their user interface to display a
>   list of peer devices for the user to choose from. Alternatively, you
>   can use the [MCNearbyServiceBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceBrowserClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MCNearbyServiceBrowser) class to look for and manage peer
>   devices programmatically.
>
> For more information about the interfaces of this framework, see
>   [Multipeer Connectivity Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328-CH1-SW1).

This class is avilable since ios7. That's fine but I think they could have given a link to this class in [GKPeerPickerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) near the deprecation message.