# GKPeerPickerController deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated, gkpeerpickercontroller

I Have a Problem When I Use This Code GKPeerPickerController And GKSession And GKPeerConnectionState

The Error I Got Is : GKPeerPickerController is deprecated : first deprecate in IOS 7

My Code Is :

> ```
> -(void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession:(GKSession *)session context:(void *)context {
>     NSKeyedUnarchiver *archiver=[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]initForReadingWithData:data];
>     NSString *str=[archiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Text"];
>     [self adicionarTexto:str fuiEu:NO];
> }
> -(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *) session {
>     currentSession = session;
>     session.delegate = self;
>     [session setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil];
>     picker.delegate = nil;
>     [picker dismiss];
> }
> -(void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker{
>     picker.delegate = nil;
>     conectado=NO;
> }
> -(void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID  didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state {
>     if (state==GKPeerStateConnected) {
>         conectado=YES;
> ```

```
    }else{
        conectado=NO;

    }
    [self atualizarBarra];
}
```

And

```
 -(void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *) session {
 currentSession = session; session.delegate = self; [session
 setDataReceiveHandler:self withContext:nil]; picker.delegate = nil;
 [picker dismiss]; }
```

And

> ```
> -(void)conectar{
>     if (conectado==NO) {
>         BTpicker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
>         BTpicker.delegate = self;
>         BTpicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
>         [BTpicker show];  
>     }else {
>         [currentSession disconnectFromAllPeers];
>     }
> }
> ```

Please I Need Help Fast :(

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem recently. You should use [MCBrowserViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCBrowserViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html). Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964021/gkpeerpickercontroller-has-been-deprecated-in-ios-7)